# How to send tokens to multiple accounts in bulk

Tags: transaction, spl, airdrop

I am following the tutorial to send a token to a specific recipient (https://spl.solana.com/token#example-transferring-tokens-to-an-explicit-recipient-token-account).
Below is the code that works where I can send the transactions 1 by one, but it would take forever for large amounts of wallets.

```
const walletsTo = [wallet1, 'wallet2, 'wallet3'...]


  walletsTo.forEach(async function (addressTo) {

    const toWallet = new PublicKey(addressTo);

    const toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      fromWallet,
      new PublicKey(mintToken),
      toWallet
    );

    let signature = await transfer(
      connection,
      fromWallet,
      fromTokenAccount.address,
      toTokenAccount.address,
      fromWallet.publicKey,
      1
    );

    console.log("Signature tx: ", signature);
  });
```

Is there a way to do the same but send the token to dozens or hundreds of recipients by batching the transactions?

**EDIT:**
Based on Rudra Sarkar help, I was able to edit the code and have it work on Devnet as below, but still getting some *Server responded with 429 Too Many Requests.  Retrying after 500ms delay...*

```
import {
  getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount,
  createTransferInstruction,
  Account,
} from "@solana/spl-token";
import {
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  PublicKey,
  clusterApiUrl,
  Transaction,
  TransactionInstruction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";

// Your passphrase in Uint8 format
const fromWalletSecretPassphrase = [];

//List of wallets
const walletsTo = [
  "wallet1",
  "wallet2",
];

const mintToken = "yourMintTokenAddress";
const transfer_amount = 30;
const numberDecimals = 6;
const batchSize = 1; // adjust your batch size according to your need

const fromWallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
  new Uint8Array(fromWalletSecretPassphrase)
);

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");

const getBatchInstructions = async (
  batch: string[],
  fromTokenAccount: Account
) => {
  const instructions = await Promise.all(
    batch.map(async (addressTo: string) => {
      const toWallet = new PublicKey(addressTo);
      const toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
        connection,
        fromWallet,
        new PublicKey(mintToken),
        toWallet
      );

      return createTransferInstruction(
        fromTokenAccount.address,
        toTokenAccount.address,
        fromWallet.publicKey,
        transfer_amount * Math.pow(10, numberDecimals)
      );
    })
  );

  return instructions;
};

const sendBatches = async () => {
  const batches: TransactionInstruction[][] = [];
  // let batches = [];

  const fromTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection,
    fromWallet,
    new PublicKey(mintToken),
    fromWallet.publicKey
  );

  console.log(
    `Sending ${transfer_amount} ${mintToken} from ${fromWallet.publicKey.toString()}`
  );

  for (let i = 0; i < walletsTo.length; i += batchSize) {
    const batch = walletsTo.slice(i, i + batchSize);
    const instructions = await getBatchInstructions(batch, fromTokenAccount);
    batches.push(instructions);
  }

  for (const batch of batches) {
    const transaction = new Transaction().add(...batch);
    transaction.feePayer = fromWallet.publicKey;
    transaction.recentBlockhash = (
      await connection.getLatestBlockhash("confirmed")
    ).blockhash;

    transaction.sign({
      publicKey: fromWallet.publicKey,
      secretKey: new Uint8Array(fromWalletSecretPassphrase),
    });

    const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(transaction.serialize());
    console.log("Batch transaction:", txid);
  }
};

sendBatches();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is inefficient for sending tokens to a large number of recipients because it processes each transfer separately because it sending the code in a synchronous way. To fix this problem what you can do is send multiple transfers to the Solana network as a single transaction using batches instead transfer it separately.

Here's a code snippet that may help you:

```
const web3 = require('@solana/web3.js');
const splToken = require('@solana/spl-token');

// Initialize connection, wallet, and token accounts for your application here

const walletsTo = ['wallet1', 'wallet2', 'wallet3'];

const getBatchInstructions = async (batch) => {
  const instructions = await Promise.all(batch.map(async addressTo => {
    const toWallet = new web3.PublicKey(addressTo);
    const toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      fromWallet,
      new PublicKey(mintToken),
      toWallet
    );

    return splToken.createTransferInstruction(
      fromTokenAccount.address,
      toTokenAccount.address,
      fromWallet.publicKey,
      1
    );
  }));

  return instructions;
};

const batches = [];
const batchSize = 10; // adjust your batch size according to your need

for (let i = 0; i < walletsTo.length; i += batchSize) {
  const batch = walletsTo.slice(i, i + batchSize);
  const instructions = await getBatchInstructions(batch);
  batches.push(instructions);
}

for (const batch of batches) {
  const transaction = new web3.Transaction().add(...batch);
  transaction.feePayer = fromWallet.publicKey;
  transaction.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getRecentBlockhash()).blockhash;

  const signedTransaction = await fromWallet.signTransaction(transaction);
  const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTransaction.serialize());
  console.log('Batch transaction:', txid);
}
```

let me know if it is working for you, If it works mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: thank you. I was able to tweak the code a bit and have it work on Devnet. However, on Mainnet,  I am getting "Server responded with 429 Too Many Requests.  Retrying after 500ms delay..." so seems like it's still sending it separately? I'll post my complete code below.

Comment: How many batch are you sending? 429 meaning rate limiting request they have limitation on the request.

Comment: Got it resolved, I needed a paid RPC API to be able to send more. Thanks a lot for the help.